# Iframe to load local resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, iframe

I have an iframe loaded from a cordova app, the url loaded within the iframe is external but I am the site owner so I can control the content. Every time it is loaded it downloads 2 MB in JS and CSS files. I would like to keep this files in mobile device to load it faster and not use data traffic.
I am able to change  content within iframe, I want to change:
     `<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.internetsite.com/css/styles.css' type='text/css' media='all' />`
to:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='LocalAppDir/css/styles.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I have tried without success:

```
href='file:///assets/www/'
href='/android_asset/www/'
href='file:///android_asset/www'
```

I cant use JS inside sandboxed iframe to get app's localdir.

I guess I need a different path for android and iOS